# Xamarin Forms: Thread not executed if page in background

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, threadpool

Some very strange issue with Threading in Xamarin.Forms:

From the `MainPage` an action is executed from the main thread (~ every 2 minutes) in a new `Thread` using

```
Debug.Writeline("now before ThreadPool");

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
            { 
                Debug.Writeline("in thread!"); 
                action1(); //takes ~ 2-3 seconds to excecute
            } );
```

However, if another page is on the top:

```
 Navigation.PushAsync(new SettingsPage(), true);
```

(and therefore MainPage in background/disappeared),  the above "workitem"  is never executed! The last debug log text actually is "now before ThreadPool", but  "in thread!" is not logged (because for some strange reason the thread is not executed...).

There is no error, it's just not executed. If MainPage is in the foreground, all works fine.
Any ideas ?

Comment: How do you push a page on top of the current one? Please include some more code in your post that shows so

Comment: @demitrian: added some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems there is a bug (or at least some unexpected limitation) in Xamarin's ThreadPool implementation:

If I replace the above `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`  with

```
new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() =>
        {
           Debug.Writeline("in thread!");                 
           action1();

        })).Start();
```

then it works just fine!

Comment: Another way to do this, I will typically use `Task.Factory.StartNew()` to start off a background task.